# JavaScript / TypeScript: ожидание выполнения асинхронного конструктора

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

Мне очень непривычно, что если я написал на TypeScript свой класс и вызываю его как-то так:

```
var result = new MyClass.search(...)
```

То метод `search()` вызовется раньше, чем завершится работа конструктора, если в конструкторе приходится использовать асинхронные функции (node.js I/O). То есть, конструктор еще не полностью закончил инициализацию объекта, а кто-то уже вызывает методы объекта. Можно ли сделать что-то подобное (аналог провожу с WinAPI):

```
search(...) {
    waitForSingleObject(event)
    ...
}
```

И пока конструктор не сделает свою работу и не вызовет:

```
setEvent(event)
```

то выполнение метода `search()` притормозится? При этом, конечно, `waitForSingleObject()` должна быть умной функцией и давать понять потоку, что пока можно заняться другими делами и не тормозить, допустим, всю платформу node.js?

P.S. Понимаю, что проблема не в TypeScript. В JS точно также функция-конструктор может создать методы у `this` и вернуть управление до того, как получит инициализирующие данные по сети, с базы, с дисковой подсистемы и т.д.

Comment: Все просто: в конструкторе не должны вызываться асинхронные функции. Конструктор не запускает работу объекта, он лишь убеждается в том, что все инварианты на месте (т.е. класс готов к работе и необходимые поля заполнены).

Comment: Конечно выполнять асинхронные ф-ии в конструкторе это плохая идея, но если очень хочется `waitForSingleObject` то можно `async/await` использовать.

Comment: А что есть асинхронный конструктор?

Comment: может тогда лучше использовать EventEmitter

Answer (score 2):

Вы неправильно понимаете приоритет операторов.

Вы кажется, что `result = new MyClass.search(...)` выполнится примерно так:

```
var tmpObj = new MyClass;
result = tmpObj.search(...);
```

но на самом деле JS понимает этот код так:

```
var tmpConstructor = MyClass.search(...);
result = new tmpConstructor;
```

Что бы код работал как в первом случае, нужно расставить скобочки. Например:

```
result = (new MyClass).search(...);
```